# Laravel - Store uploaded image path in database,retrieve and display the image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I stored a picture in the uploads folder of my laravel project, I have an image table that has column name `filename` as a string type, how can i save the uploaded image location in the `filename` column and then output in my photos blade file based on the file location in my db
This is the code I used to store my image in my uploads folder

```
         $filename = $file1->getClientOriginalName();
          $picture = date('His').$filename;
          $file1->move($destinationPath, $picture);
```

Comment: read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem and try something, tell us what is not working

Comment: Means you already stored images in upload folder and database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the steps I did regarding upload and retrieve user related images.

For the example, a user upload his profile picture which named `myfile.png`

So, for upload:

1. Get the file from `$request`
2. Get the file name with `getClientOriginalName()` (i.e. `myfile`) and also the file extension with `getClientOriginalExtension()` (i.e. `.png`)
3. Generate some random strings which will be appended to the file name to avoid file name duplication (i.e. `fx7ew6`)
4. Append the original file name with the generated random strings along with the extension (i.e. `myfile_fx7ew6.png`)
5. Save image file to folder (i.e. `public/img`) and also save the file name to the database

For retrieve:

You can use `<img src="/img/{{FILE_NAME}}">` to show the uploaded image which will result `<img src="/img/myfile_fx7ew6.png">` **IF** you upload the image to `public/img`.